# Discord.JS Slash Commands === TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Tags: javascript, discord.js, interaction, discord-buttons

I am currently having trouble with my slash commands. I am trying to get it so that in the author spot of the embed, it posts the author's Name & tag, and their profile. For some reason I keep receiving this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')**

It would be amazing if someone could help me fix this. If you need the code to help me with the issue, here is a preview of it below!

If you need to DM me to fix this issue, you can DM me. **Puggy™#9999**

````js
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Help Command',
    options: [],
    async execute(client, interaction) {
    
       const embed = new MessageEmbed()
     .setAuthor({ name: `${interaction.user.tag}`, iconURL: `${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})}`})
    .setThumbnail("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/d7TMnLgFFrq6n5ICbvBdHMK8PkBveAYydv2Z-zUMtGQ/%3Fsize%3D512/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/937174535684374528/5c1630bd97bce9ecfec7408d584eb2da.webp?width=478&height=478")
    .addField("About Atlantis Utilities", `Custom bot made for the ** Atlantis ．Community & Giveaways** discord server.`)
    .setFooter({ text: 'Use the buttons below to navigate through the help command' });
    
        const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#000000")
    .setThumbnail("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/d7TMnLgFFrq6n5ICbvBdHMK8PkBveAYydv2Z-zUMtGQ/%3Fsize%3D512/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/937174535684374528/5c1630bd97bce9ecfec7408d584eb2da.webp?width=478&height=478")
    .setTitle(`${client.user.username} Commands!`)
    .setDescription(`` + 
    "\n\n"+ "**Information Commands**\n`Avatar, BlackListWords, Help, Profile, RolePerms, Serverinfo, Stafflist, Userinfo`") //

    const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#000000")
    .setThumbnail("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/d7TMnLgFFrq6n5ICbvBdHMK8PkBveAYydv2Z-zUMtGQ/%3Fsize%3D512/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/937174535684374528/5c1630bd97bce9ecfec7408d584eb2da.webp?width=478&height=478")
    .setTitle(`${client.user.username} Commands!`)
    .setDescription(`` + 
    "\n\n"+ "**Moderation Commands**\n`Ban, BannedUsers, Hackban, Kick, ModNick, Mute, Purge, RemoveWarn, Timeout, Unban, Unmute, Warn, Warninfo, Warnings`")
    
        const embed3 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#000000")
    .setThumbnail("https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/d7TMnLgFFrq6n5ICbvBdHMK8PkBveAYydv2Z-zUMtGQ/%3Fsize%3D512/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/937174535684374528/5c1630bd97bce9ecfec7408d584eb2da.webp?width=478&height=478")
    .setTitle(`${client.user.username} Commands!`)
    .setDescription(`` + 
    "\n\n"+ "**Utility Commands**\n`Addrole, ChannelPerms, CreateRole, Cult, EditAchievement, Embed, Hire, PresetRole, RemoveRole, ResetCase, RoleEveryone, RoleEveryoneRemove`\n\n**Giveaway**\n`end-giveaway, reroll-giveawy, start-giveaway`\n\n**Configuartion**\n`config_atlantis, config_profile`\n\n**Suggestion**\n`Suggest, Accept-Suggestion, Deny-Suggestion`") 
    
    const button1 = new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('home')
    .setLabel('Home')
    .setStyle('PRIMARY')
    .setEmoji(``)
    
    const button2 = new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('help1')
    .setLabel('Information')
    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
    .setEmoji(`❓`)
    
    const button3 = new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('help2')
    .setLabel('Moderation')
    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
    .setEmoji(``)
    
    const button4 = new MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('help3')
    .setLabel('Utility')
    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
    .setEmoji(`⚙️`)
    
            const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(button1, button2, button3, button4);
    
    await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed1], components: [row]})
    
const filter = i => i.user.id === `${interaction.user.id}`;

const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 120000 });



collector.on('collect', async i => {
    if (i.customId === 'help1') {
        await i.update({ embeds: [embed2], components: [row] });
    }
});
    
    }
};```
````

Comment: Well, this error means that either `client` or `interaction` is `undefined`. Try logging them via `console.log` to see what they are. The issue probably resides in your command handler's code.

Answer (score -1):

Alrighty, so the issue was with my command handler. The issue has been solved `:D`

Comment: Please don't post answers like this because this is a comment. If you keep doing this you will be rendered unable to ask questions in SO due to the downvotes you going to receive. So please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), I'm trying to help not being rood.